# What is the criteria to choose between IocService and RegistryBuilder in Fantom afIoc

Tags: inversion-of-control, fantom

The documentation of Alien Factory's [IoC framework](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afIoc/) for [Fantom](http://fantom.org) says:

You can use IocService to start IoC as a Fantom service:

```
IocService([MyModule#]).start
...
reg     := ((IocService) Service.find(IocService#)).registry
service := reg.dependencyByType(MyService#)
...
Service.find(IocService#).uninstall
```

Or use RegistryBuilder to manage the Registry instance manually;

```
reg := RegistryBuilder().addModule(MyModule#).build.startup
...
service := reg.dependencyByType(MyService#)
...
reg.shutdown
```

But what is the criteria to decide the appropriate way of initialising the registry on a specific scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer - use `RegistryBuilder`.

The long answer prompted me to update the documentation... it's ongoing, but here's the current revision:

## Building the Registry

Use `RegistryBuilder` to manually manage an IoC `Registry` instance. You would typically do this when running tests.

```java
registry := RegistryBuilder().addModule(MyModule#).build().startup()
...
service := registry.dependencyByType(MyService#)
...
registry.shutdown()
```

Ensure modules are added from other IoC libraries the code uses. Example, if using the [IocEnv library](http://www.fantomfactory.org/pods/afIocEnv) then add `IocEnvModule`:

```java
registry := RegistryBuilder().addModule(MyModule#).addModule(IocEnvModule#).build().startup()
```

It's standard that IoC library modules are named after the library, but with a `Module` suffix.

## The IocService

If your code runs in an IoC container, such as [BedSheet](http://www.fantomfactory.org/pods/afBedSheet), then the container manages the `Registry` instance for you.

If running unit tests then typically you would create your own `Registry` instance and hold it as a variable / field.

An alternative is to create a [Fantom Service](http://fantom.org/doc/sys/Service) to hold the registry. This is useful in situations where static access to the `Registry`, such as `fwt` applications where you have very little control over how your classes are created.

`IocService` is a helper class that extends 'Service' and contains convenience methods for creating and accessing the registry.

For example, to create and start a Fantom IoC Service:

```java
IocService([MyModule#]).start()
```

Then from anywhere in your code, it may be accessed with:

```java
iocService := (IocService) Service.find(IocService#)
...
myService  := iocService.serviceById(MyService#.qname)
```

Uninstall `IocService` like any other:

```java
Service.find(IocService#).uninstall()
```